# Use the polarity distribution of word to detect the sentiment of new words

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have just started a project in NLP. Suppose I have a graph for each word that shows the polarity distribution of sentiments for that word in different sentences. I want to know what I can use to recognize the feelings of new words? Any other use you have in mind I will be happy to share.
I apologize for any possible errors in my writing. Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "graph for each word that shows the polarity distribution of sentiments for that word in different sentences"? (Can you give a pointer to somewhere that idea is more fleshed out, with data/illustration?) Also, if you have some specific theory that such info for known words might help with unknown words – perhaps by receiving new texts with a mix of known & unknown, & imputing unknown words to be similar to known words they often appear near? – the real test would be to try that approach, with your data & goals. There's no a priori assumption/analysis better than trying it.

Comment: @gojomo I mean constructing a distribution function for the word. For example, for the word sell, I create a distribution function whose point is the polarity of the sentence that contains the word sell.

Comment: @gojomo I do not mean to use word2vec and similar cases to find the similarity of the new word with the previous ones. I thought I might be able to extract useful information from its distribution function.

Comment: What is "the polarity of the sentence that contains the word sell"? Some human's hand-labeling of the sentence's positive/negative sentiment? If you weren't thinking of using word2vec, what is the meaning of tagging this question with `word2vec`? If you somehow deduced that 'sell' might be (ever-so-slighlty) negative-in-sentiment, because you had a bunch of labeled sentences that have `'sell'` in them, won't that same techique work for unknown words? It's still unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @gojomoIt is true that I could not write well what I meant.
Some human's hand-labeling of the sentence's positive / negative sentiment? Yes. With a value between -1 to +1.
For example, the distribution of word emotions is normal. How does this help me identify the feelings of the new word? (Suppose I have found similar words in another way and now I want to conclude from the normal distribution)

Comment: If there are some words that you already somehow calculated their net-sentiment effect, why can't you use the same process for additional words?

Comment: @gojomo I have calculated the polarity of the available words manually. The goal is to automate this with high accuracy

Comment: Do you  mean you've only hand-labeled words, not texts, with your -1.0 to 1.0 sentiment values?

Comment: @gojomo Yes by a few people. Now I'm going to use the known polarity distribution of known words to detect the sentiment of new words.

Comment: In general, I need an innovation to solve the problem of sentiment analysis, and I think maybe this can be achieved this way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got some words that have been hand-labeled with positive/negative sentiments, but then you encounter some new words that aren't labeled:

- If you encounter the new words totally alone, outside of contexts, there's not much you can do. (Maybe, you could go out to try to find extra texts with those new words, such as vis dictionaries or the web, then use those larger texts in the next approach.)
- If you encounter the new words inside texts that *also* include some of your hand-labeled words, you could try guessing that the new words are most like the words you already know that are closest-to, or used-in-the-same-places. This would leverage what's called "the distributional hypothesis" – words with similar distributions have similar meanings – that underlies a lot of computer natural-language analysis, including word2vec.

One simple thing to try along these lines: across all your texts, for every unknown word U, tally up the counts all neighboring words within N positions. (N could be 1, or larger.) From that, pick the top 5 words occuring most often near the unknown word, and look up your prior labels, and avergae them together (perhaps weighted by the number of occurrences.)

You'll then have a number for the new word.

Alternatively, you could train a word2vec set-of-word-vectors for all of your texts, including the unknown & know words. Then, ask that model for the N most-similar neighbors to your unknown word. (Again, N could be small or large.) Then, from among those neighbors with known labels, average them together (again perhaps weighted by similarity), to get a number for the previously unknown word.

I wouldn't particularly expect either of these techniques to work very well. The idea that individual words can have specific sentiment is somewhat weak given the way that in actual language, their meaning is heavily modified, or even reversed, by the surrounding grammar/context. But in each case these simple calculate-from-neighbors techniqyes are probably better than random guesses.

If your real aim is to calculate the overall sentiment of longer texts, like sentences, paragraphs, reviews, etc, then you should discard your labels of individual words an acquire/create labels for full texts, and apply real text-classification techniques to those larger texts. A simple word-by-word approach won't do very well compared to other techniques – as long as those techniques have plenty of labeled training data.